# Trying to add mp4parser in my project android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to integrate mp4parser [library](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

by adding

> compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4'

But it gives me error

> Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4

Comment: user : 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'

 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser/1.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

Without your *build.gradle* I'm speculating here, but I think that you are missing:

```
repositories {
   mavencentral()
}
```

in you main *build.gradle* file.

In my I have the following

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "http://repository-monochromeroad.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The second *repositories {}* block is essential.

Comment: i tried adding that too but its the same error that is coming.

Comment: then you have to post your build.gradle files somewhere for us to have a look.